# Bootstrap Modal Ajax not working on click

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Bootstrap Modal Ajax not working on click without the alert on second line.
please help
http://pastebin.com/cyXdWSPq

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in a $(document).ready(function(){}) or equivalent.  When I see stuff like this it's usually because the document is not fully loaded yet.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was using it along with datatables so due to async process the script was not properly loaded with ajax data in datatables so now i gave it a shot by                               "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    //alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    initModals();
   },