# what would cause my ajax to not follow through all commands?

Tags: php, ajax

My insert ajax code will refresh the page but then not alert ("add successful"). Data does echo the right key trigger words ADD_OK i double checked. I have no errors. This seems odd to me because I used the exact same ajax code for both my add and delete.

**Code Not Alerting But Adding to database**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).on('click','#insert_btn',function (){
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'add.php',
             datatype: "json",
            data: {
                first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
                last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
                position: $("#position").val(),
                date: $("#date").val(),
                updated: $("#updated").val(),
            }, 
            success: function(data){ 
               if (data=='ADD_OK') {
                  //  alert(data);  
                  location.reload();
                      alert("Add Successful");
                } else {
                     //alert('something wrong');
                }
                  }
             })
        }); 
</script>
```

**Code Working doing both the delete and alert**
The same code for delete will refresh page and alert ("delete successful"). What would cause this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).on('click','.delete_btn',function (){
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0];
        var del_id = $('#example').DataTable().row( id ).data();
        var del_id = del_id[0];
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            data: {del_id:del_id}, 
            success: function(data){ 
                if (data=='DEL_OK') {
                  location.reload();
                  alert("Delete Successful!");
                } else {
                 //    alert('something wrong');
                }
                  }
                     });
        }
        });
</script>
```

**Add.php Code**

```
<?php
$first_name = strtoupper($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = strtoupper($_POST['last_name']);
$position = strtoupper($_POST['position']);
$date = $_POST['date'];
$updated = $_POST['updated'];  
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, position, date, updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
   $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $first_name, $last_name, $position, $date, $updated);
   $add = $stmt->execute();

    //print_r($_POST);

   if($add) {
      echo "ADD_OK";
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap your `location.reload()` and `alert(...)` lines.

The alert will only run if the page hasn't started reloading yet.  I imagine it takes longer on some pages for a number of reasons.

Comment: unfortunately i had already tried that.  I just double checked and did it again with no success.

Comment: in my delete ajax i had reload first then alert and that one worked which is puzzling.

Comment: I don't think it should work like that, if the page reloads it will stop processing the javascript from that page and starts the session all over again on the new page load... is your delete still working that way now?

Comment: https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/    Ya my delete will alert (delete successful)

Comment: your logic/theory could be right but it is puzzling why my delete works...

Comment: does it still reload?

Comment: i believe so yes. it adds the data instantly to see. i added my add.php code too in original post.

Comment: the only difference between the two is the confirm. guess i will try adding a confirm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955019/how-to-reload-a-page-after-the-ok-click-on-the-alert-page   I probably have to do a confirm box like in that link.

Comment: Maybe need to turn ascn to false, on my phone right now so will try when I get home https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810813/ajax-post-not-working-without-alert-message

Answer (score 0):

I added code for insert data please try and check this. Also, you try this to delete and change your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).on('click','#insert_btn',function (){
      $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'add.php',
             datatype: "json",
            data: {
                first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
                last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
                position: $("#position").val(),
                date: $("#date").val(),
                updated: $("#updated").val(),
            }, 
            success: function(data){ 
               if (data.success == true) {
                  //  alert(data);  
                  alert("Add Successful");
                  location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert('something wrong');
                }
                  }
             })
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: same as mine. added but then no alert.

Comment: Please reload your script with window.location.reload(); in ajax command might help you.

Comment: i tried it again after clearing cache now it saying "something wrong"

Comment: window.location.reload() got rid of the something wrong error but still no alert.

Comment: do i need something like this maybe? ive been trying it out with no success so far: var r = confirm("Successful Message!");
    if (r == true){
      window.location.reload();
    }

Comment: You check the data added your table or not.

Comment: I checked that Error comes but data added successfully. Please remove your echo from the add.php and check.

Comment: commented out echo ADD_OK in add.php file. trying it out now.

Comment: well somehow the computer doesnt think i echo out ADD_OK. thats my conclusion. but commenting it out didnt work either.

Comment: Please comment  if condition code and alert(data)  so we check on it whats the problem.

Comment: just realized there is an error. says  'ADD_OK' is undefined

Comment: alert(data) is turned on says ADD_OK

Comment: echo json_encode seems to get rid of the undefined error but still no alert message,

Comment: Please try out result method of the success: function(result){if(result == ADD_OK){alert('OK')}else{alert('wrong')}}

Comment: new way adds to table but no alert message. I tried using both encode json and the regular echo method too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895530/bootstrap-modal-ajax-not-working-on-click   This could be it. i may have to use a full document.ready(Function()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360626/ajax-success-callback-alert-not-working Maybe I need to change success to complete? On phone will try later. What you think.

Comment: Ok, @JeffBezos. I think we try to research on success response message what return in the response to ajax do debug the code to send post data in preserve log.

Comment: Yep. I think data response is empty for whatever reason. No clue what’d cause that...

Comment: i got it to alert update_ok and something wrong now. i just commended out //something wrong. weird! but guess a half working solution is better than nothing

Comment: I may need to set Async to false, will try when I get home. What you think? Would make sense. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810813/ajax-post-not-working-without-alert-message